# Looking for articles on postcritically finite rational maps in Russian or French

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, dynamical-systems, arithmetic-dynamics, mathematical-russian

I'm looking for articles on postcritically finite rational maps.
I found a few articles in English, but I can't find any in Russian or French.